# How to override getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts to exclude restricted product from subtotal in Hybris

Tags: java, aspectj, spring-aop, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

Probably a duplicate question of [experts.hybris](https://experts.hybris.com/questions/52469/aop-proceedingjoinpoints-gettarget-value-is-null.html)

We are using promotion module(deprecated one). OOTB if you have a product restriction and you have mix cart(having allowed and restricted products) then promotion(Say: order threshold promotion) will apply(calculate) on whole cart total. **Ideally, restricted products price should be excluded from cart total to trigger promotion and this is what I want to achieve.**

To do so I'm trying to override `getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts` using Spring AOP and its also getting called. But there, I need to get current promotion class instance (OrderPromotion) to call `evaluateRestrictions` of `PromotionsManager`. But it always getting null using `(OrderPromotion) pjp.getTarget()`

**Aspects:**

```
package com.myproject.aop;

@Aspect
public class AbstractOrderAOP
{

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(AbstractOrderAOP.class);


    @Pointcut("execution(public * *..OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion.evaluate(..)) && target(orderPromotion)")
    public void evaluatePointcut(OrderPromotion orderPromotion)
    {
        //
    }

    @Pointcut("execution(protected * de.hybris.platform.promotions.jalo.OrderPromotion.getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts(..)) && args(ctx, order)")
    public void subtotalPointcut(SessionContext ctx, AbstractOrder order)
    {
        //
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("boxing")
    @Around("evaluatePointcut(orderPromotion) && cflow(subtotalPointcut(ctx, order))")
    public Object getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, OrderPromotion orderPromotion, SessionContext ctx,
            AbstractOrder order)
    {
        LOG.info("here you go ....");
        return 0l;
    }
}
```

**aop.xml**

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-Xset:weaveJavaxPackages=true">
        <include within="de.hybris.platform.promotions.jalo.OrderPromotion"/>
        <include within="de.hybris.platform.b2bacceleratorservices.jalo.promotions.OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion"/>
        <include within="com.myproject.extended.interceptor.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <aspect name="com.myproject.aop.AbstractOrderAOP"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your aspect does not import `de.hybris.platform.promotions.jalo.OrderPromotion` and is not in the same package. So I really wonder why it should even compile with the cast to `OrderPromotion` you are trying to use.

If you do have the import in your aspect and just erased it before copying it into your SO question, I see no reason why `pjp.getTarget()` should yield `null`, with one exception: If the ***method is static***, then of course it would not have a target object to be called upon because there is not object instance. In this case your aspect cannot work and you need to intercept another pointcut.

As Hybris does not seem to have any public JavaDoc on the web and I have never used it and thus no access to it, I cannot say for sure, I have to speculate.

---

**Update:** Okay, I am back from my trip and have a little time to answer. Basically the idea is to get

- the target from the calling instance method and
- the arguments from the static method.

In order to achieve that you use the `cflow()` pointcut by which you can express that the static method's execution should be captured if it is in the control flow (i.e. directly or indirectly called by) the instance method which gets you the target object. You should

- pull out the two method executions into two separate pointcuts,
- then use `args()` and `target()` in order to bind the captured values directly to pointcut parameters
- and then combine the pointcuts and all parameters in your advice method:

```java
@Aspect
public class AbstractOrderAOP {

  // (...)

  @Pointcut(
    "execution(public * *..OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion.evaluate(..)) && " +
    "target(orderPromotion)"
  )
  public void evaluatePointcut(OrderPromotion orderPromotion) {}

  @Pointcut(
    "execution(protected * *..OrderPromotion.getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts(..)) && " +
    "args(ctx, order)"
  )
  public void subtotalPointcut(SessionContext ctx, AbstractOrder order) {}

  @Around("cflow(evaluatePointcut(orderPromotion)) && subtotalPointcut(ctx, order)")
  public Object getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts(
    ProceedingJoinPoint pjp,
    OrderPromotion orderPromotion,
    SessionContext ctx,
    AbstractOrder order
  ) {

    LOG.info("############ AbstractOrderAOP is being evaluated ############");
    try {
      final Object output = pjp.proceed();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    ArrayList products = new ArrayList();

    // (...)

    return 0l;
  }

  // (...)
}
```

See? No more ugly `getTarget()` or `getArgs()[0]`, but perfectly typesafe parameter binding.

BTW, you do not need to abbreviate the package names to `*..` like I did. I just wanted to make it a bit more readable for you and other people around here.

This works and I have tested that it does by replicating all your dozen or so classed as dummies (too much code to post here).

Comment: `just erased it before copying it into your SO question` - Yes, I did so. Earlier there was no cast to `OrderPromotion`, I just changed it on SO to demonstrate what I want to do. And yes, You are right method is static. I think that could be the reason.

Comment: I have updated question with OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion and OrderPromotion. Is there any another way to I get a current caller(an instance of OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion) in aspect

Comment: Yes, there is a good AspectJ solution to your problem, but I cannot help you before Saturday or Sunday because I am travelling without PC and I want to provide code, not just prose. Sorry to keep you waiting.

Comment: It's fine. It would be great help. Thank you!!

Comment: As promised, I added the solution source code to my answer as an update. Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I will implement it and let you know how it works in my case

Comment: I tied but advise is not being invoked. I have updated my question with all OOTB classes and aspect. I have tried with `OrderThresholdFreeGiftPromotion ` which extends `GeneratedOrderThresholdFreeGiftPromotion` and indirectly `OrderPromotion`

Comment: Oh sorry, after renaming the pointcuts in my code I accidentally switched the names in the advice pointcut. It has to be `cflow(evaluatePointcut(orderPromotion)) && subtotalPointcut(ctx, order)`, **not** `evaluatePointcut(orderPromotion) && cflow(subtotalPointcut(ctx, order))`, of course. I must have forgotten to recompile and test after I did that - quite embarrassing. I also updated it in the answer.

Comment: wow... it's work, seems magic to me!! I don't understand `cflow` fully. I really appreciate if you would elaborate more on it so I can know `Where & How cflow can be applied`.

Comment: In order to learn AspectJ basics, I recommend to read the [AspectJ documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php). Specifically for a better understanding of `cflow()` and `cflowbelow()`, read [this part](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/language-joinPoints.html#pointcut-composition).

Comment: I know because I specify the type in the pointcut and advice signature. Parameter binding via `this()`, `target()`, `args()`, `@annotation()` is also described in detail in the AspectJ documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I can see specified types. That was actually my question how would I know this specified type will work? is `OrderThresholdDiscountPercentagePromotion` should be required to extend specified type like `OrderPromotion`? or I can specify any types. I know question might sound funny to you

Comment: The question does not sound funny, don't worry. I simply do not understand it. Anyway, you said my solution works. So if you have any new problems, would you mind creating a new question? I cannot give you private AspectJ lessons here, though, as much as I like to help people here. You should really read the documentation.

Comment: Sounds good. I will go through AspectJ in detail examples. I will try to ask a specific question on SO, if face any.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the AOP here, Just override the `OrderPromotion` and you should be fine :

```
<bean id="de.hybris.platform.promotions.jalo.OrderPromotion" 
    class="foo.bar.CustomOrderPromotion" 
    scope="prototype">

    <property name="timeService" ref="timeService" />
    <property name="cartService" ref="cartService" />

</bean>
```

Note: your `CustomOrderPromotion` should inherite from the `OrderPromotion`.

Comment: I think this won't work as I want to achieve this behaviour for all OOTB order promotions, `1>` OrderPromotion is abstract class `2>` all OOTB promotion indirectly extend OrderPromotion `3>` getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts is static method `4>` Out custom class (`CustomOrderPromotion`) won't invoke as it won't be referenced also we can't declare bean for it as it will also be abstract. Correct me If I'm wrong

Comment: Also, the method is `final` so it can't be overridden. Check my updated question.

Comment: Ah I see what you are trying to achieve now, unfortunately `getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts()` is final and static so you can not override it, however i noticed that `getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts()` is just invoking `order.getSubtotal(ctx)` and `order.getTotalDiscounts(ctx)` so why not to try to override `order.getTotalDiscounts(ctx)` instead and leave `getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts()` as it is?

Comment: `order.getSubtotal(ctx)` is core method which might be being invoked from many places. We should not alter order subtotal and discounts. For promotion `getOrderSubtotalAfterDiscounts` is the only method on which promotion trigger decide, so I want to change its logic like `triggerThresold=(orderSubtotal) - (restrictedProductsTotal) - (discount)`

Comment: i know that it is a core function, however you can alter its behavior depending on [something] passed withen the `ctx` for example.

Comment: let's assume we can override it, though I face the issue, as we need restricted product list (to subtract it from subtotal). Which can be fetched from restriction applied to current promotion. So how do we get the current promotion object (which is evaluating for trigger)?

Comment: `ctx` is the `SessionContext` you can put what ever you need inside it using `setAttribute()` even the entire current promotion and retrieve it later on from the `getSubtotal(ctx)` or `getTotalDiscounts(ctx)`.

Comment: Yes, I know that. But with respect to my requirement could you please point me where should I set it so with minimal change it will set for all promotion?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168610/discussion-between-hybrisfreelance-and-mouad-el-fakir).